# rpmbuild/rpm not reading the rcfile

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec, suse, sles

I am learning rpm/rpmbuild and I see strange behavior difference in RPM v4.4.2.3 and RPM v4.14.
I created an **rpmrc** file which has below content

> macrofiles:/home/rmehta/rpmtest/rpmmacros

and **rpmmacros** has below contents

> %_name Rakesh

When I execute rpmbuild `--rcfile /home/rmehta/rpmtest/rpmrc --eval %_name` it gives different output for both RPM versions
For RPM version 4.4.2.3 (SLES-15) it prints **Rakesh** 
For RPM version 4.14.3 (SLES-11) it prints **%_name**

My question is why this difference and why for RPM v4.14.3 its not reading the rcfile.

I tried same with RPM v4.11(openSUSE) and its behaviour is same as RPM v4.14.3.

Comment: Have you tried `--eval '%{_name}'` on the command line? Just a shot in the dark, sorry. Does `--showrc` give you anything useful to compare?

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco Thanks for replying. I already tried `--eval '%{_name}'` but it has same result as `--eval %_name`
On comparing output with `--showrc` flag, there are many difference but below are some differences  which I believe are important <br/> 
1) With RPM v4.4 there is no Macro path, which is there for RPM v4.14 as below <br/>
Macro Path: /usr/lib/rpm/macros:/usr/lib/rpm/macros.d/macros.*:/usr/lib/rpm/platform/%{_target}/macros:/usr/lib/rpm/fileattrs/*.attr:/usr/lib/rpm/suse/macros:/etc/  rpm/macros.*:/etc/rpm/macros:/etc/rpm/%{_target}/macros:~/.rpmmacros

Comment: 2) With RPM v4.4  the _name macro is defined as `-14:  _name  Rakesh` which is missing for RPM v4.14
3) With RPM v4.4 there is optflags : -O2 which is missing for  RPM v4.14
4) For both it has 
> RPMRC VALUES:
macrofiles            : /home/rmehta/rpmtest/rpmmacros

Comment: Sorry no idea why.